# Export html tables with large number of columns to PDF

Tags: java, pdf, html-table, export-to-pdf

I need to export html table to PDF in Java. My table has large number of columns. When I export it PDF only few columns are displayed, rest are cut off. Need suggestions on how I can display all the columns. (On the html page I used horizontal scrollbar to handle large number of columns, but no idea what to do on pdf)

Comment: How about using a 'big' page format such as  A0 instead of A4 or letter ?  See the actual sizes here : http://www.papersizes.org/a-paper-sizes.htm

Comment: But the problem is that no. of columns is based on the user input, which can be 100,200..so on. May be if I can split the table vertically...But dont know how to do that.

Comment: then you've stated your answer yourself already. Split your big table into smaller more manageable tables. And display them the ones below the others

Comment: But I dont know how to do it. I cannot do it on serverside. I have to do something in html/css.But dont know how and what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 solutions :

- Either you split your huge table into smaller tables that you can display one below the other,

  or
- You try fitting your large table "as is" onto a larger page size  such as **A1 or A0** instead of the standard A4 or letter.

  ( See the actual sizes here : http://www.papersizes.org/a-paper-sizes.htm )

  Then when you generate your pdf you should also be able to set a small zoom such as 20%, so that the document opens "zoomed out".

Comment: Can you help me with the first option. For the second option, I dont know whether the data will actually be visible on the page

Comment: Beyond the "how you'll do it" you have to see how you can split your data. Can your columns be grouped into smaller subsets ?

Comment: You've got to work out a better layout for your table. And decide on multiple smaller layouts that still make sense and are easier to handle.

Comment: Actually, you may define a document size based on the user's input. It may be bigger than A0 wide.

Comment: Indeed. Hadn't thought of that. The page size can indeed be custom defined

Comment: It was helpful. Thanks!!